# Can Android DataBinding use inner class?

Tags: java, android, inner-classes, android-databinding

UpdateActivity.java:

```
public class UpdateActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityUpdateBinding dataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_update);
    }

    interface Listener {
        void onClick(View v);
    }
}
```

activity_update.xml:

```
<data>
   <variable
       name="listener"
       type="com.kycq.reader.UpdateActivity$Listener"/>
</data>
```

if i set the 'listener',it always Errors.it is mean i can't set inner class,or i should set 'listener' on other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access inner classes using Android's data binding library as long as the inner class is declared public. I was able to use an inner class by making sure it was public. Instead of using `com.kycq.reader.UpdateActivity$Listener` use `com.kycq.reader.UpdateActivity.Listener` to access the inner class.

Comment: i know it,my question is can i use the inner class?

Comment: @csx Yes, you can use inner classes as long as they are public. Not sure why you're using a `$` instead of a `.` though.

Comment: it work! i always think the interface is default public,and the inner class must  use the $

Comment: When i use inner class e.g androidservice..ViewClickHandler Impl class generate MyService<?>.ViewClickHandler and that causing the compilation issue.